# select list in chrome jumps when option is clicked

Tags: list, google-chrome, select

I have a select list-box that extends below the bottom of browser.
When I click on an option near the bottom it makes the select list jump to even itself out with the top of the select-box even to the top of browser window.

When the size attribute is less than number of items the scroll-bar appears and it wont jump.

How do I prevent it from jumping like that?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>jump test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select size="63" name="test" id="test">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                    <option value="32">32</option>
                    <option value="33">33</option>
                    <option value="34">34</option>
                    <option value="35">35</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="37">37</option>
                    <option value="38">38</option>
                    <option value="39">39</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="41">41</option>
                    <option value="42">42</option>
                    <option value="43">43</option>
                    <option value="44">44</option>
                    <option value="45">45</option>
                    <option value="46">46</option>
                    <option value="47">47</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="49">49</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="51">51</option>
                    <option value="52">52</option>
                    <option value="53">53</option>
                    <option value="54">54</option>
                    <option value="55">55</option>
                    <option value="56">56</option>
                    <option value="57">57</option>
                    <option value="58">58</option>
                    <option value="59">59</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="61">61</option>
                    <option value="62">62</option>
                    <option value="63">63</option>
                    <option value="64">64</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it may have to do with your css. Put an explicit height on both your select and option items. Like so:

```
select,
option {
  height: 30px;
}
```

hope this helps. In case you have been breaking your head about this for the past 2 or so years.